# Shadow Jar doesn't include dependencies into fat jar

Tags: gradle, maven-shade-plugin

I am new to Gradle and to shadow jar ([Gradle version of Maven's Shade plugin](https://github.com/johnrengelman/shadow)). I am building a fat jar, in which I want to merge service files (that's why I am using shadow jar in the first place).
[According to the documentation](http://imperceptiblethoughts.com/shadow/api/com/github/jengelman/gradle/plugins/shadow/tasks/ShadowJar.html) shadowJar task inherits from gradle Jar task. So, one would assume that it will work exactly as a jar task.

Here is the snippet of the jar task:

```
 jar {
    zip64 true
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

As a result, it produces a fat jar with all the dependencies exploded, what is anticipated. When I change task name from jar to shadowJar, like below:

```
 shadowJar {
    zip64 true
    from { configurations.runtime.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
}
```

I get a jar file that contains only files from the current project, dependencies are excluded. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to define the `from...` part. The plugin will include all dependencies automatically.